# Electron - run jar file from background script

Tags: javascript, java, jar, electron

I have this code inside my electron app. I need to run a [jar file](https://github.com/yeokm1/docs-to-pdf-converter) and that will do a conversion job of some documents from  docx to pdf

```js
for (let p = 0; p < docPaths.length; p++ ) {
    const jar = childProcess.spawn(`java -jar docs-to-pdf-converter-1.7.jar -i ${docPaths[p]}, -o ${docPaths[p].replace('.docx', '.pdf')}`);
    //
    jar.stderr.on('error', () => {

    });
    //
    jar.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log(data);
    });
    //
    jar.on('exit', (code) => {
        console.log('jar ok', code);
    });
}
```

When I run the electron app I will get always this error

[image: Error screenshot]

Is possible to run a java file from an electron app? what I need to do exactli, use `exec` instead of `spawn`?